# How to refresh a route page

Tags: routes, flutter

I followed the startup name generator tutorial in the flutter website and there was no problem. 
But then I wanted to add the ability to remove wordpairs from the saved list. That worked too but when a word was removed from the list,  the listview wouldn't update and I had to go back to the main page and open the list again to see the effect. I searched for a way to update the listview at the setState function that I delete the wordpair in,  but  I could't find anything. So after removing the wordpair in the setstate, I just popped the route and pushed it again.
Can anyone suggest a better way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by making the list of saved pairs a separate stateful widget. I knew this would make the list refresh each time I deleted a pair but I thought the link between the states of the two stateful widgets would be lost and any time I deleted a pair from the list of saved pairs, the favorite icon in the other stateful widget would not update. But amazingly I was wrong. The states are somehow connected. I assume its because they're two stateful widgets on the same stack. I'm beginning to really like flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that using a `StreamBuilder`. Using that, your argument should like the following:

```
stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
      "profiles").onValue
```

As you can see, the `onValue` will automatically update your screen whenever you delete a value.

Comment: The wordpairs are stored in a set and sets don't have an onValue getter(as the error informed me). How can I transform a set to a stream? Also, streams don't seem to have any method for removing a previously sent item.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've just used the `main.dart` from the [startup name generator tutorial](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/codelab), then you can just modify your `_buildRow` function to add a delete button which will then call `setState` and modify the `_suggestions` list like this:

```
Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          pair.asPascalCase,
          style: _biggerFont,
        ),
        subtitle: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('delete'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _suggestions.remove(pair);
              });
            }));
  }
```

And here's the full `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          // Add a one-pixel-high divider widget before each row in theListView.
          if (i.isOdd) return Divider();

          final index = i ~/ 2;
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
          }
          return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          pair.asPascalCase,
          style: _biggerFont,
        ),
        subtitle: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('delete'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _suggestions.remove(pair);
              });
            }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}
```